# How to generate unique register URL in Laravel 8.*

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In my application I need register and login function. But functionality of my app requires that only some people will be able to have accounts, while I still might need to add new users.

I was thinking about 2 options.

1. Disable register routes and generate unique, 1 time register url which I would send to my future user.
2. Add column in users table and somehow only validated(by admin) users would be able to use app.

Since second option as consequence would require me to rebuild whole app Im wondering

**Is it possible to create unique register urls?**

**I havent done anything yet towards solution, I dont know where to start really so I cant provide any piece of code or error**

Comment: 3. Add a whitelisted email table and check it on registration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using signed URL's in Laravel:

```
$url = URL::signedRoute(
  'register', 
  now()->addMinutes(30)
);
```

Then we can modify our `registration` route to determine if that signed URL is valid:

```
public function register($request) {
  abort_unless($request->hasValidSignature(), 403, 'That link has expired or is no longer valid!');
  
  //they can register now
}
```

Comment: error: Unsupported operand types: int + array after first code

Comment: Can I use your method without  ['token' => Str::uuid()] ? It works that way tho.

Comment: @Michó Yes. Updated my answer to be more generic.